# How to introduce cases in a proof.

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

I am writing a simple proof in regards to a homework problem about a property of stable matching. The content of the proof isn't necessarily what I am asking about as opposed to the presentation of the proof.

If your proof has three main cases, would you first preface how they are defined and then go into each case, or just state there are three cases and jump solely into case one without stating what the other two cases are until you finish the first case entirely?

For example:

> There are three cases to observe: 'case1', 'case 2', and 'case 3'. Suppose 'case 1'...

vs.

> Observe there are three cases. Suppose 'case 1' ...

Here are my actual cases:

1. there exists $m' \in M$ such that $m' \neq m$ and $(m',w) \in S$
2. there exists $w' \in W$ such that $w' \neq w$ and $(m,w')\in S$
3. $(m',w),(m,w') \not\in S$ for all $m' \in M$ and for all $w' \in W$

Comment: I know this isn't the point of the question, but what if $M = \{m\}$, $W = \{w\}$, and $S = \{(m,w)\}$?  Then it seems like none of (1)-(3) holds.

Comment: That would be a trivial instance of the problem so I am neglecting it. The problem is just showing that if $m$ is the highest priority for $w$ and $w$ is the highest priority for $m$ then the pair $(m,w)$ must be in every possible stable matching.

Comment: I was just trying to follow Hagen's instructions and verify that the list was complete :-)  I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if the whole proof is more than a paragraph then you should state the cases up front in a numbered list.  This helps the reader understand the structure of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to introduce the cases beforehand (or alternatively summarize them in the end).
After all the reader needs to verify (or rather you need to spell out to the reader) that the cases are *complete* (there is no fourth case missing).